# jQuery UI Draggable - action on revert multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to write some kind of action to drag multiple elements with jQuery UI draggable. Dragging already works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make an action on other elements, not the one I'm dragging, but these elements which I append at the bottom of dragged elements and move them in drag action. I want them to revert on their original positions, and then remove them (those cloned). Any ideas?

```
$taskItem.draggable({
        cursor: "default",
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            if(event === false){
                return !event;
            }
        },
        start: function(e, ui){
            if($(ui.helper).hasClass("tasks-list__item--selected") === true){
                $taskItem.addClass("tasks-list__item--currently-dragged");

                tasksVC.$tasksList.find(".tasks-list__item--selected:not(.tasks-list__item--currently-dragged)").each(function(index, item){

                        var draggedItem = $(item).clone();
                        draggedItem.addClass("dragged-item");
                        $('body').append(draggedItem);

                        $(draggedItem).css({
                            position: 'absolute'
                        });
                    });
            }
        },
        drag: function(e, ui){
            if($(ui.helper).hasClass("tasks-list__item--selected") === true){
                $(".dragged-item").each(function(index, item){
                    $(item).css({
                        top: ui.position.top + (index+1)*32,
                        left: ui.position.left
                    });
                });
            }
            if($(ui.helper).hasClass("tasks-list__item--selected") === false){

            }
        },
        stop: function(e, ui){
            $('.dragged-item').remove();
            $taskItem.removeClass("tasks-list__item--currently-dragged");
        }
    });
```

I don't want to use any plugins but jquery UI draggable.